# Python add string to list while adding list items (iterating)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

This is partially working:

```
list = ["abc %d" % d for d in range(1, 1000)]
```

But I need something like:

```
list = ["a %value% bc %d" % d for d in range(1, 1000) foreach %value%]
```

`%value%` should be a 20 value list or something. Can anyone help me fix my code?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work?

```
list = ["a %s bc %d" % (v, d) for d in range(1, 1000) for v in value]
```